# How to know if a download completed in Django

Tags: python, django, download

On our Django based site, users can download "private" files.

After intern validation, these files are made available with Apache's X-Sendfile. The code looks like :

```
if "Trident/" in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
    content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % iri_to_uri(smart_bytes(filename))
elif "Safari/" in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] and not \
     "Chrome/" in request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']:
    content_disposition = b'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename.encode("utf-8")
else:
    filename_encoded = ""
    str_chunk_size = 30
    for i in range(int(math.ceil(len(filename)/float(str_chunk_size)))):
        if i != 0:
            filename_encoded += " =?UTF-8?B?"
        else:
            filename_encoded += "=?UTF-8?B?"
        filename_encoded += base64.b64encode(smart_bytes(filename[i*str_chunk_size: (i+1)*str_chunk_size])) + "?="
    content_disposition = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % filename_encoded

response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/force-download; charset=utf-8')
response['Content-Disposition'] = content_disposition
response['X-Sendfile'] = smart_bytes(os.path.join(STORAGE_ROOT, f.storage_name))
response["Content-Length"] = f.size
return response
```

The problem is that we need to know if the download went up to the last byte.
This information is security sensitive, so it needs to be obtained on server side. (javascript on client side wouldn't be trusted).

After investigation, I could find 2 ideas, but none of them seems successful.

1. Apache's log gives information on URL + how many bytes were transfered.
   Unfortunately this is not in Django context, it's complicated to parse and unmanageable in case of multi users downloading multiple files at the same time ... So bad idea.
2. Django's [request_finished](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_finished). Unfortunately it's called with only 2 parameters :

   - sender : The handler class (not an object!?)
   - signal : object which has nothing that let us find anything about what was downloaded, was that successful, how many bytes, ...

This sounds like I couldn't find any valuable way to know if the client could download the file successfully or not.

Any idea?

Comment: i don't think that hooking up to some django signal would work, simply because django sends just those headers and the rest of the process is taken care of by http server (in your case: apache).

could you setup up a daemon which does tail -f access.log and watches only for the urls which interest you and asynchronously notifies django? or would it be too inefficient?

Comment: i even found something on apache and hooks.. http://www.fmc-modeling.org/category/projects/apache/amp/3_3Extending_Apache.html

maybe you could hook up into apache's hook for request being finished? and then send a signal to the django app..

although i have no experience in apache :/